# PHP soap request accessing array in object

Tags: php, soap

I want to echo all the years in this object that was returned from my soap request.
I'm not sure how to access the array to iterate the years.
Output is from `print_r($response_year);`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetVehicleYearsResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Errors] =>   
            [Years] => stdClass Object  
                (
                    [int] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 2015
                            [1] => 2014
                            [2] => 2013
                            [3] => 2012
                            [4] => 2011
                            [5] => 2010
                            [6] => 2009
                            [7] => 2008
                            [8] => 2007
                            [9] => 2006
                            [10] => 2005
                            [11] => 2004
                            [12] => 2003
                            [13] => 2002
                            [14] => 2001
                            [15] => 2000
                            [16] => 1999
                            [17] => 1998
                            [18] => 1997
                            [19] => 1996
                            [20] => 1995
                            [21] => 1994
                        )    
                )    
        )    
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will list the years.

```
foreach ($response_year->GetVehicleYearsResult->Years->int as $year) {
  echo $year;
}
```

The array can be accessed by `$array = $response_year->GetVehicleYearsResult->Years->int;`.

Simply remember that on such structures :

- After 'Object', use `->`
- After 'Array', use `[$key]`